# Appending CSV content to predefined columns using API data

Tags: node.js, json

I am pulling JSON data through a Node.js API. First I iterate through the `list` of IDs in my input `csv` and use the id to call the output data.

Problem is the CSV content produced is not clean and difficult to read.
[Sample of output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xwQ7j93hiAEKqcN8Fw3MDN1THQFWPyLt)

I would like to create CSV content with the keys as the columns and values as the row values. For example. When I run the `getPersonById` method for a single fighter:

```
async function writeData() {
    const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
    const sample = await boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,468841)
    console.log(sample.output)
```

This is a sample of the output I get:

```
{
      date: '23 10 0',
      firstBoxerRating: [Array],
      firstBoxerWeight: 215.5,
      judges: [Array],
      links: [Object],
      location: 'Scottrade Center, Saint Louis',
      metadata: '  time: 3:00\n' +
        ' | <span>referee:</span> <a href="/en/referee/402047">Mike England</a><span> | </span><a href="/en/judge/402325">Marty Bicle</a> | <a href="/en/judge/401071">Jerry Griffin</a> | <a href="/en/judge/432852">Barbara Madison</a>\n' +
        '<br>',
      numberOfRounds: [Array],
      outcome: 'unknown',
      rating: null,
      referee: [Object],
      result: [Array],
      secondBoxer: [Object],
      secondBoxerLast6: [],
      secondBoxerRating: [Array],
      secondBoxerRecord: [Object],
      secondBoxerWeight: null,
      titles: []
    },
```

I will get a lot of these JSON files for each fight the fighter has fought. In this scenario I would want to use the keys (e.g numberOfRounds, outcome, etc.) as the column names and the values assigned to each key as the row values.

So the desired output would resemble this:

```
date       firstBoxerRating      firstBoxerWeight ...
23 10 0        [Array]                 215.5
```

With the keys in my sample as the column names.

Since everything else returned will have the same keys (i.e., date for each fight), it would make sense to append subsequent keys with +1 (so date1, date2, date3, etc.).

This is the code I have thus far:

```
async function writeData() {
    const csv = require('csv-parser')
    const results = [];
    fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\testingclean.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data',(data)=> results.push(data))
        .on('end', async () => {
          const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
          const promises = [];
          results.forEach((data) => {
            promises.push(boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,data.id));
          })
          const fighters = await Promise.all(promises);
          fighters.forEach((fighter) => {
              let data = '';
              for (const key in fighter.output) {
                  if (Array.isArray(fighter.output[key])) {
                      data += JSON.stringify(fighter.output[key]) + ',';
                  } else if (typeof fighter.output[key] === 'object') {
                      data += JSON.stringify(fighter.output[key]) + ',';
                  } else {
                      data += fighter.output[key] + ',';
                  }
              }
              data = data.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
              data += '\n';

              fs.appendFile('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\boxeroutput.csv',data, (err) => {
                  if (err) throw err;
              });
          });
        });
    };
try {
    writeData();
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in writeData: " + error);
}
```